# Why is the following returning False in LeetCode?

Tags: python

When I run the following code on my local machine, it returns True... However, when I submit the same code on LeetCode for question 334, it is failing and returning false for the test input of [14,22,21,11,90]!!! Can anyone see an issue here?

```
def increasingTriplet(nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: bool
    """
    x = sorted(list(set(nums)))
    if len(x) < 3:
        return False

    map = {}

    for i in x:
        map[i] = sorted([j for j, num in enumerate(nums) if num == i])

    
    while len(map.keys())+i>2:
        i = 0
        least = map[min(map.keys())][0]
        for key2 in list(map.keys())[1:]:
            if least < map[key2][-1]:
                i += 1
                least = [y for y in map[key2] if y > least][0]
        if i > 1:
            return True
        map.pop(min(map.keys()))

    return False

        


print(increasingTriplet([14,22,21,11,90]))
```

Here is an image of the leetcode submission in case you can catch the mistake there...

[image]

Comment: Can you describe what the function tries to achieve. Some more comments might also help.

Comment: Are you running this locally with Python3 while running it in Python 2 on the site? (In other words make sure you've selected `Python3` from the dropdown on the site.)

Comment: @Daraan The problem being considered is [this one](https://leetcode.com/problems/increasing-triplet-subsequence/). The function is supposed to return True if the array contains a strictly increasing subsequence of length 3 and False otherwise.

Comment: @Purnajyoti Using `map` as a variable name is bad practice since map is a Python keyword.

Comment: I'll add that the reason to consider the version, is that it looks like you are depending on the order of keys in a dictionary, which is unlikely to work in Python2.

Comment: Hi, I was running it locally in python3! Thanks for all of the feedback. I think @BenGrossmann's solution below is on the right track below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mark noted, your method will not work in Python 2.X because it relies on the order of keys in a dictionary. If you want to modify your method so that it works in Python 2.X, you can modify it to use the list `x` instead of the index dictionary to keep track of the keys. For example, consider the following alternative:

```
def increasingTriplet(nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: bool
    """
    x = sorted(list(set(nums)))
    if len(x) < 3:
        return False

    mp = {}

    for i in x:
        mp[i] = sorted([j for j, num in enumerate(nums) if num == i])
    
    while len(x)+i>2:
        i = 0
        least = mp[x[0]][0]
        for key2 in x[1:]:
            if least < mp[key2][-1]:
                i += 1
                least = [y for y in mp[key2] if y > least][0]
        if i > 1:
            return True
        x.pop(0)

    return False

print(increasingTriplet([14,22,21,11,90]))
```

I suspect, however, that this method will exceed the allotted time because it has O(n<sup>2</sup>) time complexity (n being the length of the list `nums`) where an optimal algorithm has complexity O(n).

As an alternative approach, I'd recommend something like the following.

```
def increasingTriplet(nums):
    min1 = min2 = float("inf")
    for x in nums:
        if x > min2:
            return True
        if x > min1:
            min2 = min(x,min2)
        min1 = min(x,min1)
    return False
```

Comment: They should really just use Python 3.

Comment: Regardless of Python2 or Python3, the alternative solution is obviously much better.

Comment: @Mark Right, that's also a reasonable option. I just wouldn't put an effort into making something work in Python 2. And I wish LeetCode would stop calling it just  "Python"... It's not the first question I've seen caused by this.